# Azure Translate API {"error":{"code":400000,"message":"One of the request inputs is not valid."}}

Tags: azure-api-management, microsoft-translator

Error related to translation using Azure's Translate API
{"error":{"code":400000,"message":"One of the request inputs is not valid."}}
i have no idea why the error message appears

[image: Settings]

[image: Error-Message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [translator documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate#request-body):

> The body of the request is a JSON array. Each array element is a JSON object with a string property named Text, which represents the string to translate.

And you are passing `text` in query string which is wrong.